# Нажатие на разные кнопки - отображение разных блоков

Tags: javascript, html

Не работает, что делаю не так? Заранее спасибо.
 Div1: набор кнопок вызывающих функцию switchVisible2(). 
 switchVisible2(): 
 функция анализирующая какая именно кнопка была нажата и отображающая нужный 
 DIV. 
 К примеру: при нажатии кнопки "togglee0" отображается DIV3, при нажатии 
 кнопки "togglee1" отображается DIV4... желательно без jQuery

```js
function switchVisible2() {
  if (document.getElementById('togglee0').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('togglee1').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('Div4').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Div4').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('togglee2').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('Div5').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Div5').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('togglee3').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('Div6').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Div6').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('togglee4').onclick) {
    document.getElementById('Div7').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Div7').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1" >
  <input type="button" id="togglee0" value="1" style="position:absolute; left:35%; top:30%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee1" value="2" style="position:absolute; left:40%; top:30%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee2" value="3" style="position:absolute; left:45%; top:30%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee3" value="4" style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:30%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee4" value="5" style="position:absolute; left:35%; top:45%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee5" value="6" style="position:absolute; left:40%; top:45%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee6" value="7" style="position:absolute; left:45%; top:45%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee7" value="8" style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:45%" onclick="switchVisible2();" />

</div>




<div id="Div3" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div3" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:30%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div3" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:35%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div3" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:40%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div3" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:45%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />

</div>

<div id="Div4" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div4" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:30%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div4" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:35%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div4" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:40%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div4" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:45%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />

</div>

<div id="Div5" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div5" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:30%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div5" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:35%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div5" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:40%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div5" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:45%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />

</div>

<div id="Div6" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div6" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:30%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div6" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:35%" onclick="openNewWin('http://');" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div6" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:40%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div6" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:45%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />

</div>

<div id="Div7" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div7" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:30%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div7" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:35%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div7" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:40%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div7" style="position:absolute; left:60%; top:45%" onclick="openNewWin('http://')" />

</div>
```

Comment: тут полностью код ?  Тогда опишите что-куда-как должно работать.

Comment: Я ничего не имею против такого оформления кода, если он не мой, но зачем Вы выкладываете код, где все элементы сами же скрыли от нас? Переправьте пожалуйста

Comment: Начните с этого https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Comment: И да, как я вижу из примера js - лучше использовать div1.children[0].classList.toggle('class') А в этот класс в css написать уже display:none/block

Comment: @Tenito Никто не обвинял. Я попросил подправить код. Да еще и пожалуйста и сказал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function switchVisible2(element) {
  if (element.className && element.className.length > 0) {
    // находим элемент на который указывает класс нажатой кнопки
    var targetEl = document.getElementById(element.className);
    var displayMode = targetEl.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    // иной способ без тернарного оператора
    // var visility = "";
    //if (targetEl.style.display === "block"){
    //    displayMode = "none";
    //}
    //else{
    //    displayMode = "block";
    //}
    targetEl.style.display = displayMode;
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  margin: 10px 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1">
  <input type="button" id="togglee0" class="Div3" value="togle1" onclick="switchVisible2(this);" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee1" class="Div4" value="toggle2" onclick="switchVisible2(this);" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee2" class="Div5" value="toggle3" onclick="switchVisible2(this);" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee3" class="Div6" value="toggle4" onclick="switchVisible2(this);" />
</div>




<div id="Div3" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div3" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div3" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div3" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div3" />

</div>

<div id="Div4" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div4" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div4" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div4" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div4" />

</div>

<div id="Div5" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div5" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div5" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div5" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div5" />

</div>

<div id="Div6" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="togglee01" value="Div6" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee02" value="Div6" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee03" value="Div6" />
  <input type="button" id="togglee04" value="Div6" />
</div>
```

Если я правильно понял - нужно чтобы кнопки прятали/показывали нужный блок элементов. Я немного поменял поведение, чтобы не писать множество обработчиков,но старался оставить основу вашего кода. За указатель я взял класс у кнопок. Т.е. я спрятал указатель но div1,2,3 и т.п. внутри класса кнопок toggle.Это не единственный способ, но самый быстрый чтобы показать пример.

Это работает следующим образом:

- Мы щелкаем по элементу (кнопке)
- Событие onclick вызывает функцию switchVisible2 с параметром this (this это ссылка на текущий элемент)
- В функции мы проверяем что у кнопки есть class (я сделал класс таким, чтобы у него было id нужного нам блока, который данная кнопка должна показать/скрыть).
- ну и собственно устанавливаем свойство display в зависимости от того, какой display сейчас имеет таргет блок (скрываем, если видно и показываем, если он скрыт).

Comment: в данном случае что бы скрыть отобразившийся блок нужно нажать на ту же кнопку, в идеале требуется что бы блок пропадал при попытке отобразить другой, есть такая возможность?

Comment: Возможно конечно, но я бы посоветовал сначала попытаться сделать это самостоятельно. Это будет вам же и полезно. Для моего кода достаточно добавить 2-3 строки в функцию. Подсказка - необходимо, перед тем как что-то показывать, скрывать все блоки кнопок кроме тех , что из первой группы (toggles)